# Sorting issue with Alpha numeric data in BI Publisher RTF Template

Tags: xml, rtf, bi-publisher

I have below XML and want to sort alpha numeric child data but having issues while sorting.

```
<LEVEL>
 <PARENT>
   <CHILD>D1</CHILD>
 </PARENT>
 <PARENT>
  <CHILD>A2</CHILD>
 </PARENT>
 <PARENT>
  <CHILD>A1</CHILD>
 </PARENT>
 <PARENT>
  <CHILD>A1</CHILD>
 </PARENT>
 <PARENT>
  <CHILD>CD1234</CHILD>
 </PARENT>
 <PARENT>
  <CHILD>1</CHILD>
 </PARENT>
 <PARENT>
  <CHILD>2</CHILD>
 </PARENT>
 <PARENT>
  <CHILD>11</CHILD>
 </PARENT>
 <PARENT>
  <CHILD>9</CHILD>
 </PARENT>
 <PARENT>
  <CHILD>4</CHILD>
 </PARENT>
 <PARENT>
  <CHILD>C3</CHILD>
 </PARENT>
 </LEVEL>
```

I tried using data type as number and text (ascending & descending). attaching tried scenarios and required output. Can you please help?

[image]

Comment: There is a huge gap between your input data and your output scenario. You tagged your question XSLT, so what does your XSLT look like so far?

Comment: Hi Sorry, I removed the tag XSLT. I want to sort it in RTF template

Comment: What is the source of the alpha numeric data? Seems like odd data to sort by.

Comment: Hi, Its reference code with a combination of letters and numbers. It can be anything. For example-> 1111,DF1234, FGH678, 23

Answer (score 0):

Sort by text first, then by number:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/LEVEL">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="PARENT">
            <xsl:sort select="translate(CHILD, '0123456789', '')" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="translate(CHILD, translate(CHILD, '0123456789', ''), '')" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="CHILD"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LEVEL>
   <CHILD>1</CHILD>
   <CHILD>2</CHILD>
   <CHILD>4</CHILD>
   <CHILD>9</CHILD>
   <CHILD>11</CHILD>
   <CHILD>A1</CHILD>
   <CHILD>A1</CHILD>
   <CHILD>A2</CHILD>
   <CHILD>C3</CHILD>
   <CHILD>CD1234</CHILD>
   <CHILD>D1</CHILD>
</LEVEL>
```

Comment: Hi I actually need it in RTF template. Apologies for adding XSLT tag